Why does my Windows roaming profile always change to a local profile on a particular PC?
Whenever I delete my user profile using Remove-CimInstance or Advanced System Properties and then log on to the same PC again, my profile will be created as a local profile instead of a roaming profile.
This means that any settings made on that PC will not be synchronised back to the user profile directory on the network share and are lost when I log on elsewhere.
When I log on to another PC of the domain, the profile is created as a normal roaming profile.
What causes the profile to be created as a local profile on this particular PC instead of a roaming profile?
Win32_UserProfile
The Win32_UserProfile looks like this
AppDataRoaming                   : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Contacts                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Desktop                          : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Documents                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Downloads                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Favorites                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
HealthStatus                     : 3 (Not Applicable)
LastAttemptedProfileDownloadTime :
LastAttemptedProfileUploadTime   :
LastBackgroundRegistryUploadTime :
LastDownloadTime                 :
LastUploadTime                   :
LastUseTime                      : 27.09.2024 12:19:24
Links                            : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Loaded                           : True
LocalPath                        : C:\\Users\\username
Music                            : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Pictures                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
RefCount                         :
RoamingConfigured                : False
RoamingPath                      :
RoamingPreference                :
SavedGames                       : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Searches                         : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
SID                              : S-1-5-21-1234567890-123456789-123456789-1234
Special                          : False
StartMenu                        : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
Status                           : 0 (The status of the profile is not set.)
Videos                           : Win32_FolderRedirectionHealth
PSComputerName                   :

via Win32_UserProfile class reference and
gcim -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | ?{ $_.LocalPath -like "$env:USERPROFILE" }

ProfileList registry entry
And the Windows Registry entry from the ProfileList is
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1234567890-123456789-123456789-1234]
"ProfileImagePath"=hex(2):... (C:\Users\username)
"Flags"=dword:00000000
"FullProfile"=dword:00000001
"State"=dword:00000304
"Sid"=...
"Guid"=...
"LocalProfileLoadTimeLow"=dword:a21ef567
"LocalProfileLoadTimeHigh"=dword:01db0f24
"ProfileAttemptedProfileDownloadTimeLow"=dword:00000000
"ProfileAttemptedProfileDownloadTimeHigh"=dword:00000000
"ProfileLoadTimeLow"=dword:00000000
"ProfileLoadTimeHigh"=dword:00000000
"NextLogonCacheable"=dword:00000001

State 0x00000304 (772) means
004 = PROFILE_NEW_LOCAL
Using a new local profile.

100 = PROFILE_ADMIN_USER
Using administrator profile.

200 = DEFAULT_NET_READY
Default net profile is available & ready.


Have you ever set up that PC to have a local account, as opposed to logging in via Microsoft?

I have only ever used a local or domain account to log on, never a Microsoft account.

I had Apache set up as a service running with my user credentials. (C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -k install) This caused a stub of the user profile to be created each time on boot, resulting in me getting a local profile instead of a roaming profile. After uninstalling the service and removing the profile again, I now get a roaming profile as intended.
One clue was that I had to go into safe mode to delete the profile because the Win32_UserProfile was always "Loaded: True". tasklist /v (docs) and handle -a -u (docs) helped to identify the service.
